# why is (3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1 / 4 + 6) = 7?

Tags: python

I am working through some python exercises and one contains the above equation(in the question posed). I thought that with order of operations it would look like this
-->{[(3+2+1-5+4) %2]- (1/4) + 6}
where (3+2+1-5+4)=**5**, then **5**  % 2 = **1** then  **1** - 1 / 4 =.75 then **.75** + 6 = 6.75
*6.75 being the final answer*, or so I thought. Can someone please help explain where I am going wrong in my understanding of how this equation is being calculated? Please keep in mind I normally use brackets myself in math to keep thing straight but I apparently do not know where to put them in this equation.

Comment: See [Python operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Comment: its much more like 3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + (4 % 2) - (1 / 4) + 6

Comment: In Python 2, division with `/` always returned an integer, so `1/4` is `0`. In Python 3, the result is `6.75`.

Comment: note i missed putting float in front of the equation in the title. not sure how to edit it.

Comment: @bcgeogirl There is an `edit` below the question. Also note that Python 2 has reached its end of life almost a year ago and Python 3 is usually the tool to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, 3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1 /4 + 6  = 3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + (4 % 2) - (1 / 4 ) + 6. So the mathematical response is indeed 6.75 (you did manage to have the good answer with a false reasoning). However, in python 2, operator "/" works as a floor division for integer - and if one of the arguments is a float, it then returns a float value. Apparently you work with python 2, that's why 1/4 = 0. Thus the response is 7 in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If your education system is based on the British system there is a mathematic rule known as BODMAS whiles the US called it PEMDAS,

It a collection of rules that reflect conventions about which procedures to perform first in order to evaluate a given mathematical expression.

example: 2 + 3 × 4 is interpreted to have the value 2 + (3 × 4) = 14, and not (2 + 3) × 4 = 20.

BODMAS(BEDMAS) stands for Brackets, Exponents, Division, Multiplication, Addition and Subtraction. PEMDAS stands for Parentheses, Exponents, Multiplication, Division, Addition, Subtraction.

I hope this answered your question. read more at *https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order%20of%20operations*